# Can a function in an sqlalchemy class perform a query?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I may be guilty of thinking in too object-oriented a manner here, but I keep coming back to a certain pattern which doesn't look SQL-friendly at all.

**Simplified description:-**

I have an Attendance table, with various attributes including clockin, lunchout, lunchin, and clockout (all of type Time), an employee ID, and a date.

Different employees can have different shift hours, which depends on the day of the week and day of the month. The employee's categories are summarized in an Employees table, the shift hours etc. are summarized in an Hours table. A Leave table specifies half/full day leave taken.

I have raw check-in times from another source (third party, basically consider this a csv) which I sort and then need to insert to the Attendance table properly, by which I imagine I should be doing:-
a) Take the earliest time as clockin
b) Take the latest time as clockout
c) Compare remaining times with assigned lunch hours according to an employee's shift for the day

c) is the one giving me problems, as some employees check-in at odd times (perhaps they need to run out for an hour to meet a client), and some simply don't check-in for meals (eating in, etc). So I need to fuzzy-match the remaining times with assigned lunch hours, meaning I have to access the Hours table as well.

I'm trying to do all of this in a function within the Attendance class, so that it looks something like this:-

```
class Attendance(Base):
    ... my attributes ...
    def calc_attendance(self, listOfTimes):
        # Do the necessary
```

However it looks like I'd be required to do more queries within the calc_attendance function. Not even sure if that's possible, and certainly doesn't look like something I should be doing.

I could do multiple queries in the calling function, but that seems more messy. I've also considered multiple joins so the requisite information (for each employee per day) is available. Neither of them feel right, please do correct me though, if necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, yes you seem to be trying to jam everything into one class, but that is not "wrong" it's just which class  you're jamming things into.

to answer the actual question: Yes, you can perform a query inside another class, and or make that class turn itself into a dict or other iter-able format which makes comparing things easier in some ways.

However I have found in practice it is usually more efficient from a time perspective to build a class per table and apply modifications to that table's specific data using the internal functions, and a overriding umbrella "job" class that performs the specific "tasks" comparison, data input, etc... for the group but which encapsulates this process so that it can scale up and be used by other higher level classes in future. This allows for table specific work done in their respective classes, but the group to be compared and fuzzy matched without cluttering up their respective tables. This makes maintaining the code easier and splitting the work amongst a group possible. It also allows for a much sharper focus on each task. In theory would also allow for asyncio and other optimizations in future.

so:
Main Job (class)
 
(various comparison functions,data input verification, etc...)
  |-> table 1 class instance 
  |-> table 2 class instance

happy to help further if you need actual examples.

Comment: Thanks, but I do understand so examples not needed. I ended up doing more queries in the calling function even after you gave this answer, simply because the logic I have to implement doesn't fit well into your structure. I guess my calling function fulfils the umbrella role you mention. It's still REALLY messy, but at least it works so far.